# How can I redirect fixed lines to a new file with shell

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I know we can use `>` to redirect IO to a file. While I want to write fixed line to a file.

For example,

`more something`  will output 3210 lines, then I want

line 1~1000  in `file1`

line 1001~2000 in `file2`

line `2001~3000` in `file3`

line `3001~3210` in `file4`.

How can I do it with `SHELL` script?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` command is what you need.

```
split -l 1000 your_file.txt "prefix"
```

Where:

`-l` - split in lines.

`1000` - The number of lines to split.

`your_file.txt` - The file you want to split.

`prefix` - A prefix to the output files' names.

Example for a file of 3210 lines:

```
# Generate the file
$ seq 3210 > your_file.txt

# Split the file
$ split -l 1000 your_file.txt "prefix"

# Check the output files' names
$ ls prefix*
prefixaa  prefixab  prefixac  prefixad

# Check all files' ending 
$ tail prefixa*
==> prefixaa <==
991
992
993
994
995
996
997
998
999
1000

==> prefixab <==
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000

==> prefixac <==
2991
2992
2993
2994
2995
2996
2997
2998
2999
3000

==> prefixad <==
3201
3202
3203
3204
3205
3206
3207
3208
3209
3210
```